# Is there any GeoCast or broadcast Protocol implemented in veins demo example?

Tags: omnet++

- Is there any GeoCast or broadcast Protocol implemented in veins demo?
- Is there any default suppression technique implemented such as (
  Slotted p-Persistence , Slotted 1-Persistence , Weighted
  p-Persistence )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veins is a generic framework and in his demo it shows how to implement a  nonsensical protocol for information dissemination.However, it use a native suppression technique without any optimization.Each vehicle only relays a single event message without duplication.

For more details about suppression techniques :[http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4407231&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D4407231](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4407231)

Try also the [Platooning Extension for Veins](https://plexe.car2x.org/). It's an extension of Veins which permits the realistic simulation of platooning (i.e., automated car-following) systems. It features realistic vehicle dynamics and several cruise control models, permitting the analysis of control systems, large-scale and mixed scenario, as well as networking protocols and cooperative maneuver.

Answer (score 1):

No. The Veins demo only shows how to implement a (deliberately) nonsensical protocol for information dissemination.